# Verifying Stokes' Theorem on upper half of torus

Tags: multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem

I'm having trouble verifying Stokes' theorem given a vector field $F(x,y,z)=(y,z,x)$ and the surface $S$, where $S$ is the upper half of the torus generated by rotating the circle $(x-b)^2+z^2=a^2$ about the $z$-axis. I think I've pretty much got the parametrization of $S$, but I don't know what to use for my bounds for that side of Stokes' theorem. Further, on the other side, with the line integral, I have no idea what $C$ should be... any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does it help to know that $b-a\leq x \leq b+a$ and $-a\leq z\leq a$?

Comment: $C$ will be the boundary of the surface, oriented so that if you walk along $C$ in the positive direction on the outside of the surface (per the surface's orientation), the surface would always be on your left. The boundary of this surface is quite obvious. Just be aware that it is in two pieces. $C$ will consist of both.

Comment: I am deleting my answer to this as all it does is a disservice to you, Please see my comment here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3462346/parametrizing-the-region-between-a-paraboloid-and-a-plane